# Check if there is any option then show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if there is an option in select then show the div if not then hide. I am not checking selected option I am checking all options.

```js
if (jQuery(".sd select option").text() == 'S') {
  console.log('hello');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-box sd">
  <select name="options[1261]" id="select_1261" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="6888" price="0">S </option>
    <option value="6889" price="0">M </option>
  </select>                                
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your markup to the question

Comment: `$('.sd select option').length` to check if a select has options. `$('YourDivSelector').hide()/.show()` for hide or show a div.

Comment: @NoOorZ24 i want to check it on page load

Comment: please add the proper markups in your question

Comment: @Fran there is different option on different pages so i want to check it on page load if there is option then show

Comment: @Bapaarcom - You can put my example code into your application to execute at pageload and go from there, updating the selectors as needed off course.

Comment: @Fran you are doing it by length i want to check by values any suggestion

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid done

Comment: @winseybash done

Comment: @Bapaarcom Ah, OK, I must have misread that. In that case, `var hasOption = $('.sd select option').filter(function(){return this.text === 'S'}).length > 0;` You might need to connect that with `.trim()` and/or `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: @Fran thank you can you add answer and show me how it would be done with if conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is an option in select

You can use `.filter()` to iterate over the options and check them length of the matched items, similar to this.

```js
var hasOptionS = $('select option').filter(function(){return this.text.trim().toUpperCase() === 'S'}).length > 0;

var hasOptionP = $('select option').filter(function(){return this.text.trim().toUpperCase() === 'P'}).length > 0;

console.log('has Option S:', hasOptionS);
console.log('has Option P:', hasOptionP);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-box sd">
        <select name="options[1261]" id="select_1261" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="">
         <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
         <option value="6888" price="0">S </option>
         <option value="6889" price="0">M </option>
        </select>                                
    </div>
```

> then show the div if not then hide

Ones you have the result you can use it in your conditional check, similar to this:

```
if(hasOption){
  $(yourDiv).show();
} else {
  $(yourDiv).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var theSelect = document.getElementById("select_1261");
var stop = false;
for (var i = 0; i < theSelect.options.length & stop != true; i++) {
  switch (theSelect.options[i].innerHTML) {
    case "S ":
    case "M ":
      document.getElementById("cooldiv").style.display = "none";//hide the div
      stop = true;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: id is constantly changing on refresh

Comment: @Bapaarcom, if we need to show you how to pull the proper Div, ask another question with the relevant information to help you. There is nothing in your opening post that can help me help you with that part.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.dropdown').each(function() {
  var _length = $(this).children('option').length - 1;
  //console.log(_length);
  
  if (_length < 1) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown-box">
  <p>Has values:</p>
  <div class="input-box">
    <select name="options[1261]" id="select_1261" class="dropdown">
       <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
       <option value="6888" price="0">S </option>
       <option value="6889" price="0">M </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-box">
  <p>Has no values:</p>
  <div class="input-box">
    <select name="options[1261]" id="select_1261" class="dropdown">
       <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but there always value on drop down so we need check on page load if value is S then show div not change